# Love2D Lua no idea why this doesn't work

Tags: lua, love2d

Apologies for the unhelpful title but I really don't know what to call this. Anyway, I can't tell why this works:

```
local entity = require "entity"
entity:new(5,10,15,6)
local test = entity
print(test.x,test.y)
```

...but this doesn't...

```
local entity = require "entity"
local test = entity:new(5,10,15,6)
print(test.x,test.y)
```

Entity.lua simple contains:

```
local Entity = {}

function Entity:new(x,y,w,h)
  self.x = x
  self.y = y
  self.width = w
  self.height = h
end

return Entity
```

Comment: Maybe because 'Entity:new' doesn't return anything. It stores all data in the 'Entity' object.

Comment: @Cold Shine It returns Entity at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1:

variable **entity** gets table which is returned from Entity.lua.

When you call Entity:new() in Entity.lua all the variable initialization is performed on table(object) **entity**. So, **entity** has variables x, y, width and height. You assigned table to **test** and printed it.

It works.

Case 2:

`local test = Entity:new()`.

Here variable **test** takes return value of method new(), which is nil in this case, because function doesn't return any value.

It prints an error because table **test** doesn't have any keys called x and y.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new table with x, y, w, h you can do :

```
function Entity.new(x,y,w,h)
  local newEntity = {}
  newEntity.x = x
  newEntity.y = y
  newEntity.width = w
  newEntity.height = h
  return newEntity
end
```

or (but less readable) :

```
function Entity.new(x,y,w,h)
  return {x = x, y = y, width = w, height = h}
end
```